# Link onclick not firing in jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, onclick

That's an excerpt of my HTML:

```
<section id="order">

                 <div id="warenkorb-button" class="warenkorb-bg-color"><a id="wk-btn-a" href="#warenkorb">zum Warenkorb hinzuf&uuml;gen</a></div>

         </section>
```

That's my JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
                 $(document).on('click', '#warenkorb-button a', function(xyz){
                              alert('test');
                              xyz.stopImmediatePropagation();                                   
                              });
});
```

That's not working/firing - if I rewrite it like that it's working:

```
$(function() {
                 $('#warenkorb-button a').on('click', function(xyz){
                              alert('test');  
                              xyz.stopImmediatePropagation();  
                              });
});
```

Comment: what happens if you change document for 'body'?

Comment: This is working for me, i tried it on jsfiddle. COuld it become from the browser? Are you sure the problem is not coming from something else?

Comment: It seems to work for me. I get the alert in both cases. Does it fail with all browsers ?

Comment: Your code is working well, what's the problem then?

Comment: So Iam not stupid... ;) Thanks for testing. I dunno why it's not working but it could be an issue with something else - have to test it...